# SQL count with two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

was wondering if someone could help a newbie out with some sql?

[image]

Right so basically I want to get all the **CustomerID's** associated with a certain **countrycode** I can get that by doing a simple query on the customer table however I then need to find out how many forms the customer has submitted in the order table.

so in summary I need to get a list of **customerID's** from the **Customer** table and count how many time they show up in the **Order** table.

What's the easiest way to go about this?

P.S. please ignore any data type / relationship issues with the image above, it's just an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables, filter on country code and group the results:

```sql
SELECT   CustomerID, COUNT(*)
FROM     query_test.customer JOIN query_test.Order USING (CustomerID)
WHERE    query_test.customer.countrycode = ?
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
SELECT
  c.customerID, 
  count(o.form_id) AS form_count
FROM
  customer c INNER JOIN order o
    ON c.customerID = o.customerID
WHERE 
    c.countrycode = ??
GROUP BY
    c.customerID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have customers that don't have any orders, then you will want a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, COUNT(o.CustomerID) as NumOrders, COUNT(distinct FormID) as NumForms
FROM query_test.customer c LEFT JOIN
     query_test.Order o
     on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerId
WHERE c.countrycode = ?
GROUP BY c.CustomerID;
```

Note this counts both the number of orders and the number of forms.